# Get Exif data from ACTION_SEND intent (TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)

Tags: android, android-intent

It seems like this question is everywhere on SO but *nothing* is working. I am sending an intent from the Android camera to my app (sharing a image taken with my Android camera to my app).

in my `framgent`:

```
// ...
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = null;

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        // ...
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            if (imageUri != null) {
                Log.v(null, imageUri.getPath());
                try {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageUri.getPath());
                    String str = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
                    Log.v(null, "lat "+str);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // ...
            }
        }
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        initComponents(view);
        initListeners();
    }
    return view;
}
// ...
```

Log.v(null, imageUri.getPath()); prints out `/external/images/media/5670`

The error appears: `E/JHEAD﹕ can't open '/external/images/media/5670'` and then `Log.v(null, "lat "+str);` prints out `lat null`?

Answer (score 1):

`imageUri.getPath()` does not return a filesystem path, because [a `Uri` is not a file](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). The weak implementation of `ExifInterface` that is supplied in the Android SDK does not support reading in from an `InputStream`, which is what you would need to consume that `Uri` reliably, using a `ContentResolver`.

You will probably need to switch to using another EXIF library. I am using [Google's AOSP one from the Mms app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master/src/com/android/mms/exif/) in my CWAC-Camera library.